# Jade - conditional to write out javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, pug

Im struggling to translate my HTML/JavaScript to Jade. Here is the source:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='../assets/js/jquery.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Can anyone advise how I would define this using Jade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of Jade don't have a syntax for [conditional comments](http://jade-lang.com/reference/comments/), but they can be included as-is.

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
// ...
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

To include inline JavaScript, you'll want it treated as [plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) so Jade doesn't try to parse it. One option for this is to add a `.` suffix to the element.

```
script.
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='../assets/js/jquery.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
```